# Nginx location for long list of prefixes

Tags: nginx

What is the best way to write location directive for long list of url prefixes

```
location ~ ^/someUrl/par1/|^/someUrl/par3/|^/someUrl/par2/|^/someUrl/par4/|^/someUrl/par5/ {
   return 404;
}
```

This list grows very fast. 
I can't use [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) directive. I the have list of prefixes, not full paths.

Is it possible to put prefixes to separate file?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a map directive?

Comment: @RichardSmith how I can do prefix filtration with map?

Comment: See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/441751/nginx-url-rewrites-and-performance/442037#442037).

Comment: @RichardSmith you can use map directive only with url full match

Comment: You can also use regular expressions.